# What is the justification for this voice-over towards the end of Bride Wars?

Tags: analysis, dialogue, bride-wars

I was watching [Bride Wars](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bride_Wars) on TV, and could not make sense of this voice-over (taken from [here](https://www.springfieldspringfield.co.uk/movie_script.php?movie=bride-wars))  towards the end:

> The one person you can count on for a lifetime, the one person who knows you, sometimes better than you know yourself, is the same person who's been standing beside you all along.

**It is contradictory and confusing**, because:

1. the two women (Emma and Liv) declare war after a slight misunderstanding  (not really knowing each each other)
2. the two brides fight in horrible ways (not really counting on each other)
3. the two are not willing to change the wedding date for the sake of the other (not really counting on each other)
4. Liv regrets doing bad only after Emma's father blesses her (not because of any thing Emma did, but because of her father)
5. Initially Liv wanted to do bad to Emma by showing some bad DVD; when she regrets it, she tries to change the DVD. If she had successfully changed it, Emma would have married someone who was not right for her. It was Liv's assistant who did not change the DVD and unintentionally cancelled the marriage. (Either way, not really a case of counting on each other)

**Now, it is all sentimental and mushy to say that Emma and Liv are counting on each other and know each other, but the facts of the movie are not in support.**

What then, is the justification for this voice-over towards the end of Bride Wars?